# TextBox - Bound Property Name

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, binding

I have a list of TextBoxes which are bound to different properties.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Width="300" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" LostFocus="TextBox_Validate"/>
```

I would like to write ONE handler such as

```
private void TextBox_Validate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var textBox = (sender as TextBox);
            if(textBox!=null)
            {
                var propertyName = X; // Get propertyName textBox.Text is bound to.
                CurrentDataContext.ValidateFields("Name"); // Name in this specific textBox
            }
        }
```

Is it possible to get the name of the property so I won't have to write many different methods that do the same thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
var expression = textBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
if (expression != null && expression.ParentBinding != null)
{
    var propertyName = expression.ParentBinding.Path.Path;
}
```

**Edit**

Or you can use `BindingOperations.GetBinding` as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.getbindingexpression.aspx). I'm not sure if one way is better than the other.

Comment: Fantastic! Just what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Name the TextBox in xaml, `x:Name="MyTextBox"`, then you can check it, `textBox.Name == "MyTextBox"`.

Comment: I don't think that it the best solution. In case of few fields being bonded to same property, I would have to work out some pattern ie. `fieldType_propertyName` naming for all fields.